# include variable value in innerHTML to create running index for input id's and placeholders

Tags: javascript, selector, innerhtml

```js
 document.getElementById('addplace').addEventListener('click', addplace);

j=1;
function addplace() {
  var node = document.createElement("li"); // Create a <li> node
  node.innerHTML = "<input id=''place'+j+' placeholder='+j+' onFocus='geolocate()' type='text' />"               
  document.getElementById("waypoints").appendChild(node);
  j++;
}
```

```html
<ul id="waypoints"></ul>
<input id="addplace" type="submit"/>
```

Instead of the text '+j+' appearing as the placeholder I want a running index 1, 2, 3, etc. I ultimately want it to be like "Waypoint 1" "Waypoint 2" "Waypoint 3" as the placeholder, likewise for the id's i want them to be place 1, place 2, place 3, etc. Thank you for your help. I have seen other related questions suggesting + sign to concatenate but it doesn't appear to be working for this application.

Comment: Like this `node.innerHTML='<input id="place'+j+'" />';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just using the wrong quotation marks:

```
node.innerHTML = "<input id='place" + j +"' placeholder='" + j + "' onFocus='geolocate()' type='text' />";
```

This will concatenate the string perfectly and insert your number accordingly.

**EDIT**

Just for the future, es6 has the ability to create "Template Strings" wich is not yet usable in every browser:

```
node.innerHTML = `<input id="place ${j}" placeholder="${j}" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />`;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need put "s to end your strings:

```
 node.innerHTML = "<input id='place" +j+ "' placeholder='" +j+ "' onFocus='geolocate()' type='text' />"
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to your question, but you could clean the code a bit by putting the `addplace` callback function into the event handler as an argument like so:

```
document.getElementById('addplace').addEventListener('click', addplace)
```

Comment: Good to know. Edited.